# Django filters update query when user changes value in dropdown filter

Tags: python-3.x, django, forms, django-filter

I have a filter that is for my model that is a `select` of all the values in that columns. I would like to make it so that when the user select a value from the `select` it automatically filters the data without the need for a submit button. I believe I need an `onclick` attribute for the `select` field but I cant figure out how to set that up for filter forms.

**filters.py**

```py
import django_filters
from django_filters import CharFilter, AllValuesFilter

from .models import *


class SetFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains', label='', )
    type = AllValuesFilter(field_name='type', choices=Set.objects.values_list('type', flat=True).distinct(), label='', )

    class Meta:
        model = Set
        fields = ''
        exclude = ['']
```

**sets.html:**

```html
<td class="d-none d-xl-table-cell">{{ myFilter.form.type }}</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `jquery` or pure `Javascript` to react on user actions.
here is code with jQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_type').bind('change', function(event) {
        $('#you_form_id').trigger("submit");
    });
});
```

here we check when user changes field `type` and then automatically submit filter form